# Text in Button in JQuery Mobile, I want to set an text left and right of the button

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, jquery-mobile

I want to set text in a jquery button to the left and to the right like in the following image?

```
<ul id="listid" data-theme="c" data-role="listview"> 

   <li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">Text 1</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">Date 
   1</p></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">Text 2</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">Date 
   2</p></a></li>

</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class `ui-li-aside` for this purpose:

```
<ul id="listid" data-theme="c" data-role="listview"> 
   <li>
    <a href="#">
      <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Text 1</h3>
      <p class="ui-li-desc">Date 1</p>
      <p class="ui-li-aside">Score 1</p>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">
      <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Text 2</h3>
      <p class="ui-li-desc">Date 2</p>
      <p class="ui-li-aside">Score 2</p>
    </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```